# Creating Soap Request with Xml Document in java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I need to make this soap request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Update xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <doc>xml</doc>
    </Update>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in that `<doc>xml</doc>` this is the field where i have to add Xml document file but its all time getting String formate. so how to now make this Soap request can anybody give me idea.

I have tried CDATA but at the other end its giving error while giving request.

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://tempuri.org/";
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", serverURI);
        SOAPElement sOAPElement = envelope.addChildElement("Update", "tem");

        SOAPElement xml_APElement = sOAPElement.addChildElement("doc", "tem");
        CDATASection aSection = soapPart.createCDATASection(builder.toString());
        xml_APElement.appendChild(aSection);




        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "Update");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
```

Comment: You working code please

Comment: is builder a StringBuilder ? what is the content in it?

Comment: Its XML file. and its having Jtree Xml file that i build

Comment: are its not class object. dont u understand that what is XML FILE IS??

Comment: I understand what an XML FIle is but you should clarify by which mean you are reading this XML File and creating a Java Object ?

Comment: Aree i just want to send that file into the SOAP request just see my request that i have to make for that look at that..

Comment: very Straight forward dude i just need to send xml file into the proper format in soap just that is it.